# iTextSharp for some reason is not writing to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, itext

My code

```
 using (iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate()))
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
                document.Open();
                List<IElement> objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(html), null);
                foreach (IElement element in objects)
                {
                    if (element.Chunks.Select(x => x.Content).Contains("page_break_here")) document.Add(Chunk.NEXTPAGE);
                    else document.Add(element);
                }


                byte[] docArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

memoryStream.Length is 16

and when I try this:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fullPdfFileAddress, FileMode.Create));
```

it creates file just fine, but i need to write it into memoryStream.

Comment: You might need to close the document before it is written to the stream. Try moving the `memoryStream.ToArray()` outside the outer `using` block. Or calling `document.Close()` before it.

Comment: getting this "+  Length 'memoryStream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' long {System.ObjectDisposedException}
"

Comment: I believe PdfWriter has an option to leave the Stream open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100645/itextsharp-for-some-reason-is-not-writing-to-memorystream/21100922#comment31743452_21100645): The document will only be fully written to the stream when it is closed. However, `PdfWriter` closes the associated stream as well by default, giving rise to your `ObjectDisposedException`. You can prevent this from happening by setting its `CloseStream` property to `false`:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate()))
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        writer.CloseStream = false;

        // Write PDF here.
    }

    byte[] docArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```